# Best way to multi page report on VB?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, report

So, this could be a little bit large...
I have a stored procedure that returns this table:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXsIq.png)

I colored for the explanation: columns in yellow are data for the headers, and columns in green are the detail rows for every header.

The treatment for this table is the next:

I want to group the rows by `IdClient` and `IdCar` (the table is ordered with this sequence) in this case the result are four groups (marked in blue and gray because they are different combinations).

I need that the groups resulted of this grouping process splits on distinct tables (pages), and every table with different header (according data from yellow columns) and obviously with its own detail list (rows from the green columns).

So if you can understand, the result from the image above would be this four pages (tables):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmJQ7.png)

What is the best way to do it? Consider than in this case the result are 4 groups, but it could be more... or less.

I was trying with reportviewer control and a dataset... and I can get and show the entire table... but how group it? and split it in 4 tables (pages) different?

Is this the way? Are there any other ways?

Help please.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm not allowed to put images on posts... yet...